# I can't seem to get my perimeter and area method to pull from different elements in the .txt file

Tags: c#

I can't seem to get the rectangle method to pull the 3rd and 4th element in the text file. I'm assuming it's pulling a different element from data.txt.

RECTANGLE CLASS

```
public Rectangle(double xCoord, double yCoord, double width, double height) 
    {
        this.xCoord = xCoord;
        this.yCoord = yCoord;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void SetWidth(double width)
    {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void SetHeight(double height)
    {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double GetWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    public double GetHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public double GetPerimeter()
    {
        return 2* (width*height);

    }

    public double GetArea()
    {
        return width * height;
    }

    public override string DisplayString()
    {
        string output = string.Format("RECTANGLE:  X: {0} Y: {1} W: {2} H: {3} AREA: {4} PER: {4}"
                  , xCoord, yCoord, width, height, GetArea(), GetPerimeter()  );

        return output;
    }
```

TEXT FILE

```
c|1.1|2.2|3.3
r|1.1|2.2|3.3|4.4
c|2.2|3.3|4.4
r|2.2|3.3|4.4|5.5
```

CLASS THAT READS THE TXT FILE AND ADJUST THE DISPLAY

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                var elements = line.Split('|');

                xcoord = Convert.ToDouble(elements[1]);
                ycoord = Convert.ToDouble(elements[2]);

                if (elements[0].ToLower().Equals("c"))
                {
                    radius = Convert.ToDouble(elements[3]);
                    tempshape = new Circle(xcoord, ycoord, radius);
                }

                if (elements[0].ToLower().Equals("r"))
                {

                    width = Convert.ToDouble(elements[3]);
                    height = Convert.ToDouble(elements[4]);

                    tempshape = new Rectangle(xcoord, ycoord, width, height);
                }
```

Another assumption I believe can be the problem is in element 3 and 4 in the if statement of the rectangle class but can't figure it out past that.

Comment: The code looks fine. Does it compile? What's the error message?

Comment: To be honest nothing looks that wrong.. What is going wrong and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: "I'm assuming...", "Another assumption..."  Why?  Have you set breakpoints and run your code?  Done *any* basic debugging?

Comment: @SQLHacks so there isn't an error message but when I set breakpoints on the width element it is defaulting to 0 and I have absolutely 0 idea why it is doing that even though I have it set to 3.3 in the txt file

Comment: @Matt So it does run which is good and the circle runs perfectly but the rectangle spits out the same answer for the perimeter and area, which shouldn't happen. For instance the second line spits out 14.52 for both the area and perimeter instead of area: 14.52 and perimeter: 29.04

Comment: Do you think that you're calculating the perimeter correctly? `2* (width * height)`?

Comment: @Jimi yes, I was. I made a test for that particular method, so I knew the formula wasn't the problem. I have it figured out now. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the same parameter for both area and perimeter (`GetArea()`). I suppose you meant to have `PER: {5}`:

```cs
    public override string DisplayString()
    {
        string output = string.Format("RECTANGLE:  X: {0} Y: {1} W: {2} H: {3} AREA: {4} PER: {5}"
                  , xCoord, yCoord, width, height, GetArea(), GetPerimeter()  );

        return output;
    }
```

PS: Sorry, I suppose this should be a comment but I can't post one comment yet.

Comment: Well spotted! That's an answer and deserves to be marked as such.